# Configuring Solr to use UUID as a key

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I am trying to configure Solr 4 to work with UUID and so far I am unsuccessful

From reading the documentation I have seen two different ways to configure schema.xml to work with UUID (both do not work)

for both I need to write

```
<fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />
```

option 1: 
add:

```
<field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NEW" multiValued="false"/>
```

and make sure to remove the line

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

option 2
add:

```
<field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Both options are not working correctly and returning
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error initializing QueryElevationComponent.

I also tried adding a row to the colrconfig.xml file with the configuration:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="uuid">
<processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory"> 
    <str name="fieldName">uniqueKey</str> 
</processor>    
<processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Thanks,

Shimon

Comment: Does your basic setup work without trying to change the type of the id field? The QueryElevationComponent error sounds like it could be a general config problem

Comment: yes it works, when setting id to string all is well

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr 4 - missing required field: uuid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914324/solr-4-missing-required-field-uuid)

Answer (score 8):

After some work here is the solution:

In schema.xml, add (or edit) the field field

```xml
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

In solr config, update the chain and add the chain to the handlers (Example: for /update/extract):

```xml
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="uuid">
  <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="fieldName">id</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>`         

<requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                startup="lazy"
                class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="lowernames">true</str>
    <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>
    <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
    <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
    <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
    <str name="update.chain">uuid</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: you may also add a query parameter "&update.chain=uuid" to your update query URL in order to trigger the UUID generation without need to define a custom request handler

Answer (score -1):

You may want to remove the Query Elevation component if not using it.

QueryElevationComponent requires unique key to be defined and it should be a string unique key with [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1520).

However, it was fixed with the Solr 4.0 alpha so it would depend what Solr version you are using.

This limitation is [documented in the Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent#elevate.xml).

Comment: Hi Jayendra thanks for your reply. I am using the latest version of Solr 4.4.0. Also, from what I understand concerning QueryElevationComponent I can disable it when querying but my problem is that when I define the field id as uuid the core will not load. Anyway, adding UUId support seems to me to be a basic operation that I would like to add without removing any components.

Comment: you would need to remove query elevation component and as disabling it would not work as it depends on the unique key.