# JSON logfile into Solr via Apache nifi

Tags: json, solr, apache-nifi

I'm tring to read a json log file and insert into solr collection using apache nifi.logfile is in following format(one json object perline)

```
{"@timestamp": "2017-02-18T02:16:50.496+04:00","message": "hello"}
{"@timestamp": "2017-02-18T02:16:50.496+04:00","message": "hello"}
{ "@timestamp": "2017-02-18T02:16:50.496+04:00","message": "hello"}
```

I was able to load the file and split by lines using different processes. How can i proceed further ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`PutSolrContentStream`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.solr.PutSolrContentStream/) processor to write content to Solr from Apache NiFi. If each flowfile contains a single JSON record (and you should ensure you are splitting the JSON correctly even if it covers multiple lines, so examine `SplitJSON` vs. `SplitText`), each will be written to Solr as a different document. You can also use `MergeContent` to write in batches and be more efficient.

Bryan Bende wrote a [good article](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/indexing_tweets_with_nifi_and) on the Apache site on how to use this processor.

Comment: thanks @Andy, that helped. Now is it possible to add an id element(for solr) to each json record ?

Comment: If you are just looking for a unique id for each document it would probably be easier to do this on the Solr side of things https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698651/configuring-solr-to-use-uuid-as-a-key