# Use of Solrj with UUIDs

Tags: java, spring, uuid, solrj

I am trying to use solrj with UUIDs but they are coming back as Strings in the SolrDocument so the reflection fails on the "getBeans" method.

I get following exception. org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.BindingException: Could not instantiate at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder.getBean(DocumentObjectBinder.java:68)

Has anyone faced similar issues with UUIDs?

Comment: this answer could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/18761756/2371309

Comment: I do not think there's a simple answer to this. A similar question was asked at http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/UUID-and-solrj-treated-as-String-td4038351.html and left unanswered (means you need to treat IDs as Strings)